# Upload large File from client to GDrive using google-api-client using resumable upload in flask/python storing in memory

Tags: python, flask, file-upload, google-drive-api, google-api-client

I am trying to upload a large file to gdrive using the google-api-client.
I am using the resumable upload. The problem here is I don't want the file object to be saved/write in my file system. I want it to read it in chunks and therefore upload the same chunks to Gdrive using resumable upload. Is there anyway where this can be achieved where i can send chunks via the google api python client.

Here is my sample Code which works but it gets the entire file object from client.

```
@app.route('/upload', methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def upload_buffer():
    drive = cred()
    if request.method == "POST":
        mime_type = request.headers['Content-Type']
         body = {
        'name': "op.pdf",
        'mimeType': mime_type,
         }

         chunk = BytesIO(request.stream.read()) # as you can see here the entire file stream is obtained 

         #I want to read in chunks and simultaneously send that chunk to GDrive

         #chunk = BytesIO(request.stream.read(1024))     

         #if I send like the above only some part of the file is uploaded in Gdrive

         media_body = MediaIoBaseUpload(chunk, chunksize = 1024, mimetype=mime_type,
                                   resumable=True)

         return drive.files().create(body=body,
                     media_body=media_body,
                     fields='id,name,mimeType,createdTime,modifiedTime').execute()

    return render_template("upload_image.html")
```

<------------------------------------------------------------------->
This is how I approached using the Google Rest APIs

```
@app.route('/upload3', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def upload_buff():

if request.method == "POST":
    Content_Length = request.headers['Content-Length']

    access_token = '####'

    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token, "Content-Type": "application/json", "Content-Length": Content_Length}
    params = {
        "name": "file_name.pdf",
        "mimeType": "application/pdf"
    }
    r = requests.post("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable", headers=headers, data=json.dumps(params))

    location = r.headers['Location']
    print("----------------------------------------------------")
    print("GDrive Upload url : ", location)
    print("----------------------------------------------------")

    start = str(0)
    while True:
        chunk = request.stream.read(1024 * 1024)
        chunk_size = len(chunk)
        print("----------------------------------------------------")
        print("Size of Received Chunk From Client:  ", chunk_size)
        print("----------------------------------------------------")
        if chunk_size == 0:
            break
        end = str(int(start)+chunk_size-1)
        headers = {'Content-Range': 'bytes '+start+'-' + end + '/' +str(Content_Length), 'Content-Length': str(chunk_size)}
        start = str(int(end)+1)
        print("The headers set for the chunk upload : ", headers)
        r = requests.put(location, headers=headers, data=chunk)
        print("----------------------------------------------------")
        print("Response content : ", r.content)
        print("Response headers : ", r.headers)
        print("Response status : ", r.status_code)
        print("----------------------------------------------------")
    return r.content

return render_template("upload_image.html")
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading your question and code I assume that you saved the stream in a variable called `chunk` and want to divide it into 1024 bytes blocks to use a [resumable upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resumable). If my comprehension of the question is correct, you can use slicing in the [bytes object](https://docs.python.org/3.1/c-api/bytes.html) `chunk` in a way similar to this:

```py
chunk = b"\x04\x09\x09\x01\x01\x01\x00\x03" # Example values
chunk[:3] # Equals to b"\x04\x09\x09"
chunk[-3:] # Equals to b"\x01\x00\x03"
chunk[4:2] # Equals to b"\x01\x01"
```

You can use this approach to slice the `chunk` into 1024 bytes pieces. Please, ask me any question if you need more help.

---

I apologize for my faulty comprehension of your question. I now understand that you have a bytes object divided into chunks and want to upload it to Drive using a resumable upload. If my actual assumption is correct, you can use the code that I wrote for that scenario. With this code there is no need to write anything on the hard drive.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
import locale
import requests
import sys
from io import BytesIO

accessToken = \
    '{YOUR ACCESS TOKEN HERE}'
fileData = \
    BytesIO(requests.get('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cf/Alhambra_evening_panorama_Mirador_San_Nicolas_sRGB-1.jpg'
            ).content).getvalue()
fileSize = sys.getsizeof(fileData) - 129

# Step I - Chop data into chunks
wholeSize = fileSize
chunkSize = 4980736  # Almost 5 MB
chunkTally = 0
chunkData = []
while wholeSize > 0:
    if (chunkTally + 1) * chunkSize > fileSize:
        chunkData.append(fileData[chunkTally * chunkSize:fileSize])
    else:
        chunkData.append(fileData[chunkTally * chunkSize:(chunkTally
                         + 1) * chunkSize])
    wholeSize -= chunkSize
    chunkTally += 1

# Step II - Initiate resumable upload
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
parameters = {'name': 'alhambra.jpg',
          'description': 'Evening panorama of Alhambra from Mirador de San Nicol\xc3\xa1s, Granada, Spain.'}
r = \
    requests.post('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable'
                  , headers=headers, data=json.dumps(parameters))
location = r.headers['location']

# Step III - File upload
chunkTally = 0
for chunk in chunkData:
    if (chunkTally + 1) * chunkSize - 1 > fileSize - 1:
        finalByte = fileSize - 1
        chunkLength = fileSize - chunkTally * chunkSize
    else:
        finalByte = (chunkTally + 1) * chunkSize - 1
        chunkLength = chunkSize
    headers = {'Content-Length': str(chunkLength),
               'Content-Range': 'bytes ' + str(chunkTally * chunkSize) \
               + '-' + str(finalByte) + '/' + str(fileSize)}
    r = requests.put(location, headers=headers, data=chunk)
    print(r.text)  # Response
    chunkTally += 1
```

As an example, this script will take a [photo](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Alhambra_evening_panorama_Mirador_San_Nicolas_sRGB-1.jpg) from Wikimedia Commons; you can use your file stream instead. After getting the data the code will calculate the file size based on the memory space used by the variable (because it isn't written on the hard drive).

The next step is to chop the file into chunks smaller than 5 MB. I made sure to use a multiple of 1024*256 as is detailed on the [docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#multiple-chunks). The data will be iterated until it's divided in *almost* 5 MB chunks (except the final one).

After that operation the code will initialize a resumable upload as [documented](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#start-resumable) using [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) for authentication. In this step I used some example metadata for my file, but you can read on [Files properties](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource-representations) about other ones. Finally, the script will save the location for future uploads in a variable.

In the final step the chunks will be iterated and uploaded one by one. First a header is built based on the [specifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#multiple-chunks). After that, we already have the header, chunk and upload location ready, so we can proceed to formalize the upload in a request. After every chunk is uploaded the response will be printed to log errors and, after the final chunk, to show the metadata of the uploaded file. This marks the end of the complete operation. As a final note I want to mention that I wrote and tested this script in Python3. If you have any doubts, please don't hesitate to ask me for some clarifications.

Comment: I am sorry if my question was conveyed incorrect. Slicing the chunk is not a problem.I need a way where the sliced chunk can be uploaded in multiple requests via resumable upload using the below code. 

#Media_body = MediaIoBaseUpload(chunk, chunksize = 1024, mimetype=mime_type, resumable=True) 

where I can send chunk by chunk to gdrive

Comment: Hi there @Jimisaac! I modified my original answer to approach your question in a different way. I apologize for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Hi @Jacques. Good approach. Appreciate your effort here. I have also implemented a similar kind of approach using rest api after some research. But I have a question here , the variable "fileData" will still hold the size of the file while execution .I am not sure that will be a good approach where uploading files of size 5GB. I have tried and tested by sending a file stream using request.stream object in flask and it worked. Any suggestions or pointers from your side is welcome. Please check the code which i have commented.

Comment: I don't see any problems with files of 5 GB or more. The method [`sys.maxsize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize) will print the highest byte size that your system could use. In a 64 bits system it is usually 9,223.37 PB (2.15 GB for 32 bits systems). Did you test `fileData` with a 5 GB file? If so, please share that file so I can study the behaviour closely.